# How do I find similar names from database?

Tags: mysql, sql

I do have 500k datas.

how do I find similar names from data base??

example for `"Microsoft" -> Microsys,Microcode,Microsystems,Microgroup...etc`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Three different ways, then the real answer.

```
CREATE TABLE company_names (
    company_name VARCHAR(35) PRIMARY KEY
);

INSERT INTO company_names VALUES ('Microsoft');
INSERT INTO company_names VALUES ('Microcode');
INSERT INTO company_names VALUES ('TrendMicro');
INSERT INTO company_names VALUES ('Microphones, Inc.');
INSERT INTO company_names VALUES ('Softonic');
INSERT INTO company_names VALUES ('Soft Touch Cleaning');
INSERT INTO company_names VALUES ('Software Systems');
INSERT INTO company_names VALUES ('SoftTouch Movers');
```

1. SELECT company_name FROM company_names ORDER BY SUBSTR(company_name, 1,4);
2. SELECT company_name FROM company_names WHERE company_name LIKE 'Micro%';
3. SELECT company_name FROM company_names WHERE company_name LIKE '%Micro%';

But if your goal is to find similar businesses, I wouldn't rely on similarities in their names. In the USA, I'd probably buy a list from infousa.com, based on the SIC code or NAICS code. You can see how those codes work at the [NAICS Association](http://www.naics.com/search.htm) web site.

Comment: see this names are already in database. I cant reinsert it as the table structure is different. and the unique index is with company names. so I hope Micro% may work...but will it delay the results?? I am using MySQL

Comment: Expressions like 'Micro%' can take advantage of a simple index. Expressions like '%Micro%' can't. If it seems slow, use EXPLAIN SELECT... to see MySQL's query plan. That should tell you whether it's using an index.

Answer (score 1):

With MySQL there is a command "SOUNDS LIKE" that lists all phonetically similar entries. I'm sure there is something similar for all other DB systems.

Comment: Phonetic algorithms--soundex, metaphone, etc--were designed to encode what people's names sound like. They're really not very good at encoding company names.

Comment: According to the tags to this question, MySQL is the database we deal with.

Comment: I guess it depends a little what he wants to achieve, but you are right.

Answer (score 1):

it has been quite a while since the question but I believe the original problem could be solved easily with some distance algorithm. I would suggest [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance)

[This article](https://www.lucidar.me/en/web-dev/levenshtein-distance-in-mysql/) explains how to implement levenshtein distance in MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have some logic on grouping the similar names or how you define the term "Similar". For "similar" does not only mean first few characters matching words. For eg:- in this case "**Microsoft**" can give you results as Microsys, Microcode etc.. but the other words like software, softtonic etc also will be considered as similar.

Well the logic is left to you, and then you can split your original string accordingly and then search in the table using **LIKE '%%'** clause.

Comment: I am looking for similarities in names only. not what they do or their business

Comment: @aron n - You can use LIKE as I have mentioned in answer. But again the similarities means it is defined by you. For eg:- similar to microsoft means, you have to decide if other words which contain "micro" are similar or "mic" or "micr" or words that match "soft" are similar or both.